# extracting data from a website (spotify) using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, spotify, extractor

I'm trying to extract text data from a list on spotify (a list of artists I follow) using javascript console in firefox browser. I'm using this code to extract all the artist names from the elements with class 'title':

```
  artists = document.getElementsByClassName('title')
```

Unfortunately, in Firefox I only get 4 random elements that having nothing to do with the artists. However in Chrome it works, I'll get a list with all the artist names as a output. **But only** after I selected one element using the inspector function first.

Unfortunely Chrome doesn't proper load the spotify webpage so the list is incomplete. How can I make this work using the Firefox javascript console?

Maybe it has something to do with the Spotify webpage is only visible after logging into my account.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would assume you are having a selector specificity problem. Can you provide a url, or steps to get to the screen you are attempting to do this on?

Comment: I go to https://play.spotify.com/user, then I login, and navigate to 'my account' and click on 'following'; which shows a list of all the artist I follow. Then I scroll down, which causes more of the list to load. I keep scrolling down until the complete list is loaded ( 1500+ artists)

Comment: In Chrome the list loading stops halfway. I run the code and it will give about 900 artists names. In Firefox the code doesn't work at all (apart from 4 irrelevant results).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
var all = document.querySelectorAll('.following .title');
all.forEach(function(item) { console.log(item.innerHTML) })
```

When I run this in my console I get something like this. You could of course add each text item to a new array and do whatever with it.

[image: Followed artists in Spotify web player console]

Comment: Looking a bit closer, that content exists in an iframe, so you will need to make sure that you are running the code in the correct frame.

Also, the browser support for that forEach is spotty. You may need to rewrite that part with an old fashioned loop, browser version depending.

Comment: Thank you. This code works great. And indeed iframes was the problem in firefox. Thanks again